# How can I devide users into different groups(Identity pools) automatically?

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-cognito

I'm using AWS Cognito in my iOS app to implement the user signup & signin functions. I used the official Amplify SDK DOCs(https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/ios/authentication) as a reference, and the app works well. But, actually I want to give my users different access authority which can achieve different contents(like files in S3).

While the user signing up the app, they must choose a group. Based on the group, they are given different access authority.

I've read the SDK DOCs and developer guide but I haven't found a good way to implement this function.

Is there any function in cognito I can use to separate users into different Identity pools? Or can anybody show me some samples which allow users having different access authority.

```
AWSMobileClient.sharedInstance().signUp(username: "your_username",
                                        password: "Abc@123!",
                                        userAttributes: ["email":"john@doe.com", "phone_number": "+1973123456"]) { (signUpResult, error) in
    if let signUpResult = signUpResult {
        switch(signUpResult.signUpConfirmationState) {
        case .confirmed:
            print("User is signed up and confirmed.")
        case .unconfirmed:
            print("User is not confirmed and needs verification via \(signUpResult.codeDeliveryDetails!.deliveryMedium) sent at \(signUpResult.codeDeliveryDetails!.destination!)")
        case .unknown:
            print("Unexpected case")
        }
    } else if let error = error {
        if let error = error as? AWSMobileClientError {
            switch(error) {
            case .usernameExists(let message):
                print(message)
            default:
                break
            }
        }
        print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to put users in different identity pools. Cognito already has [user groups](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-amazon-cognito-groups-and-fine-grained-role-based-access-control-2/) that you can use to assign different roles. 
I am not familiar with IOS but there should be an **admin add user to group** method that you can use.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I'll try to find how to use the adminaddusertogroup method.